# How to change header background color and font color in Handsontable

Tags: handsontable

**Questions**: I'm able to change background color of cells but not of the header. Can I change the background color as well as font color of the header in Handsontable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use jquery or css for this. For example, apply a background color to all the span.colHeader:

```
.handsontable span.colHeader {
    text-color: #B2B2FF; /* pink ish */
    background-color: #FF7878; /* red */
}
```

Or even easier, handsontable allows HTML for col headers so as an option, you can supply an array of the headers with HTML:

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: items,
  startRows: 1,
  colHeaders: ['<label id="header1" style="background-color: blue">I'm the first header"</label>', '<label id="header2" style="background-color: red">I'm the second header"</label>']
  }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Add style tag in head of document.  This will affect all HOT grids on the page.
Still researching how to make different grids display with different styling.

```
   .handsontable table thead th{
        background-color: green;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:12px;
    }
```

Comment: Place each HOT in its own div with a class. Then use the appropriate selector. `<div class="divHot1"><div id="divHOTTable">...` In your css, select using `div.divHot1 .handsontable table thead th`

Answer (score 1):

test this css to change handsontable header color

```css
.handsontable th {color: #f5ffa5 !important; background: #78DEFF !important; }
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Do not just post code.